# help to understand files in sites/all/default/files/js folder

Tags: files

I'd like to understand what are the ....js.gz files located in `sites/all/default/files/js`.

I thought they are cached js files.

But if I clear all caches (drush cc all) these files still remain there.

I've made a capture of the folder:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like you said these are just cached versions of the javascript files. Drupal compresses them so they can be served to the user faster, notice the difference in file size between the version 29.1 KB opposed to 117.4 KB.

Are there any error when you clear cache through drush? Mostly I've found that they stay behind when you run drush as a user that cannot modify the files, e.g. a user not in whatever group owns the files. In this case you need to add your user to whatever group owns the files.

Comment: Not sure if I get you right, but if I run drush status the **Drupal User is anonymous**. Should I run some drush command to change to **Drupal User to admin** ?

Comment: I meant the linux/osx user your running the command from. Drush will be run with the same permissions as the user your running it from, can you try rm filename.js.gz? If you can't remove the file that way then there's your problem.

Comment: I understand. I have no problem removing the file with `rm filename.js.gz`. Then I don't know why these files are not deleted when clearing all caches...

Comment: Are these files really in sites/all/default/files? Or sites/default/files? If the former, is sites/all/default/files really the configured directory for your files, as set at `admin/config/media/file-system`?

Comment: You get js and css files of the type in your image by checking ` Aggregate and compress CSS files.` & ` Aggregate JavaScript files.` @/admin/config/development/performance. If you run `$ sudo drush cc all` they clean up but for the latest ones.